# Making selection mode for recyclerview selection tracker activate only on long press

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Created a recyclerview and added the `recyclerview-selection 1.0.0` to track selection, the implementation of the selection tracker works okay except for the fact that a simple click/tap on a recyclerview mode starts a selection. I was of the impression that the tracker out of the box only allows the selection mode when user long presses an allowed recyclerview row, how can I prevent the selection mode from being triggered on row tap? I have tried the following to no avail

```
selectionTracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>("connection_selection",
            recyclerView,
            new TransactionHistoryListAdapter.KeyProvider(adapter),
            new TransactionHistoryListAdapter.DetailsLookup(recyclerView),
            StorageStrategy.createStringStorage())
            .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.<String>createSelectAnything())
            .withOnItemActivatedListener(new OnItemActivatedListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemActivated(@NonNull ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<String> item, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withOnDragInitiatedListener(new OnDragInitiatedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDragInitiated(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDragInitiated");
                    return true;
                }

            })
            .build();
    adapter.setSelectionTracker(selectionTracker);
```

Answer (score 4):

in your `ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails` implementation set `inSelectionHotspot` to `false`. This prevents the selection via single tap.

```
override fun inSelectionHotspot(s: MotionEvent): Boolean = false
```

Comment: This implementation works: https://github.com/ExpensiveBelly/RecyclerViewSelection

It's basically this: https://github.com/ExpensiveBelly/RecyclerViewSelection/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/recyclerviewselection/ViewExtensions.kt

Comment: Removing that line itself will work